# Cannot type in Search textbox of tokenInput Jquery plugin using local data and tokenLimit

Tags: jquery, plugins, types, input, token

I am using tokeninput plugin in my application where data is fetched from JSP servlets and rendered on UI. This scenario involves getting a list of service areas like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Service Area1"},{"id":2,"name":"Service Area2"},{"id":3,"name":"Service Area3"},{"id":4,"name":"Service Area4"},{"id":5,"name":"Service Area5"},{"id":6,"name":"Service Area6"}]
```

This JSON object is provided in JSP using input hidden tag

```
<input type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${serviceAreaList}"></c:out>" id = "serviceAreaList" />
```

where serviceAreaList is an object returned from java server side code.

now i have an input text box of form

```
<input type="text" name="serviceArea" class="input-field142" maxlength="15" id="choose_lis3" name="serviceArea"/>
```

the tokeninput is applied as:

```
var serviceAreaList = $("#serviceAreaList").val();
$( 'input[id=choose_lis3]' ).tokenInput(serviceAreaList, {tokenLimit: 3});
```

but now when in UI i cannot type in the search textbox field. Am i doing something wrong? i debugged the tokeninput code and the query string is coming as empty "" cos i cannot type anything in the text.

Comment: Don't you think the `"` will conflict? If you use `<input type="hidden" value="[{"id":1,"name":"Service Area1"},{` can you see how the `"` will mess everything up? At the same time, you can't just open/close the `value` with `'` instead, because there may be `'` in the values of the JSON.

Comment: We did think of "" before but it is not the issue because in the generated html the json is parsed into options. We also noted that the plugin behaves different in chrome and firefox. I have posted another question related to this on [stackoverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899292/jquery-combobox-autocomplete-with-min-characters-support).